# when I use gulp I get a weird js output?

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify

I'm using gulp with reactjs and browserify

Here's my gulp file

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    reactify = require('reactify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename')


gulp.task('js-build', function() {
      // converts jsx to js
    var b = browserify({
        entries: ['./lib/main.jsx'],
        transform: [reactify],
        extensions: ['.js','.jsx'],
        debug: false,
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {},
        fullPaths: false
    });

    function build(file) {
        return b
        .plugin('minifyify', {
            map: false
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));
    }
});

gulp.task('default', ['js-build']);
```

When I run gulp to convert my jsx to one js file, my js file output is really long and complicated and has functions that are beyond what I specified in my jsx files? Like there is a function called cleanUpNextTick() for example that I never declared.

Is this normal?

Here's my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "browserify": "^11.0.1",
    "expect": "^1.9.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-react": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.4",
    "jest-cli": "^0.5.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "marked": "^0.3.5",
    "minifyify": "^7.0.5",
    "react": "^0.13.3",
    "react-tools": "^0.13.3",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "jsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "scriptPreprocessor": "preprocessor.js",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "node_modules/react"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-cli": "^0.4.19"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's normal, your code is been transpiled into Javascript ES5 by reactify, which uses `ReactTools.transform` under the hood.

The new features of the language are being replaced with ES5-compatible code, and new functions can be added to the final code during the transformation.

Also, browserify bundles all the dependencies you referenced to with `require` (or ES6's `import`), so you'll see also third-party code in your final bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its definitely normal. The bundle file compiles ALL javascript in your project, including your node module. This means youll be able to see functions from anything you require, `cleanUpNextTick` if probably from one of the libraries youre requiring, like react's `CSSTransitionGroup` for example